# Erasure of method is the same as another method

Tags: java, generics

[image: https://postimg.cc/75ff28ST]

from the above image, why

```
<T extends Number> void method1(T t)
```

and

```
<T extends Number, U extends List<String>> U method1(T t)
```

consider as same method but

```
<T> void method1(T t)
```

is allowed?

Comment: All three are the same method, and you can only have that method **once**. All three become `void method1(Object t)` after type erasure (the second one isn't void, but it's the same signature `method1` that takes one object argument).

Comment: For reference: [Oracle's tutorial on type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Actually, the first two are `method1(Number t)`. The third one is `medthod1(Object t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your methods and their erasure:

1. ```
   <T extends Number> void method1(T t)
   ```

   would have the erasure

   ```
   void method1(Number t)
   ```

   because every `T` is `Number` or one of it's subclasses.
2. ```
   <T extends Number, U extends List<String>> U method1(T t)
   ```

   has the erasure

   ```
   List method1(Number t)
   ```

   Again, because every `T` is `Number` or it's subclass.
3. ```
   <T> void method1(T t)
   ```

   has the erasure

   ```
   void method1(Object t)
   ```

   because `T` can be any class.

As you can see, the erasures (without the return type) for 1. and 2. are equal.
3. Is different, so it is allowed as overload.